# Is there a good JSON formatter library for PHP or JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, json

Before I code one myself, I was wondering if there's a library out there, for PHP or JavaScript that can take a one-line JSON string and format it with tabs and line breaks so it's easy to read.

Here is an online tool that does it: http://www.jsonlint.com/

I just need to format the string, validation isn't needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're happy doing it in Javascript, modern varieties of [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_JSON_in_Firefox#Converting_objects_into_JSON) have an optional argument, which sets the number of spaces to pretty-print with.  For example, using an example object from that page:

```
var foo = {foundation: "Mozilla", model: "box", week: 45, transport: "car", month: 7};
console.log(JSON.stringify(foo, null, 4));
```

This outputs:

```
{
    "foundation": "Mozilla",
    "model": "box",
    "week": 45,
    "transport": "car",
    "month": 7
}
```

Comment: calling as JSON.stringify( object, null, '\t'); makes it look really nice

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, but

```
print_r(json_decode($jsonStr));
```

conveys most of the same info unless you really need to display json.

As of php 5.4, there's a new flag(JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) for [json_encode](http://www.php.net/json_encode)

```
echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one I used recently:

https://gist.github.com/773216

Answer (score 1):

Try \Zend_Json::prettyPrint();

```
$json = json_encode($myData);
echo Zend_Json::prettyPrint($json, array("indent" => " "));
```

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.json.basics.html#zend.json.basics.prettyprint

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple formatting function in the PHP manual:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#80339

If you want the best JSON pretty-printer available in PHP, then use:

```
 $json = escapeshellcmd($json);
 $json = `echo '$json' | python -m json.tool`;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to examine the JSON object itself for debugging

```
<?php
  echo "<pre>" . print_r(json_decode( $json_object_as_flat_string, true )) . "</pre>"
```

or in Firebug/Webkit Console just do

```
console.log($json_data)
```

If you need to display the object in HTML output, look at something like 
http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/prettyprint-for-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

For Javascript, use the JSON library (json2.js) available at http://www.json.org/js.html

Your JSON must be valid, but it's just a simple matter of:

`JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(your_json_string), null, "  ")`, where the last argument is the string used for indentation (2 spaces, in this case)

Answer (score 0):

I use perltidy, it does complain, but it doesnt hurt anything, and it makes a garbled up json look alot nicer... and half the time you already have perltidy on a machine already (nice when you are running on someone elses machine with no privs to install)

```
perltidy -se myfile.json -o myfile-formatted.json
```

If you don't like the .ERR file showing up which since it isn't actually a perl file, will. Then you can just add `-se &> /dev/null` to the end of that, which tell perltidy to print errors to stdout, and to redirect any messages to /dev/null so you won't see them.